# ArcGIS webpack plugin for rendering map, Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'esri/Map'

Tags: webpack, arcgis-js-api, react-typescript

Here is the repository
https://github.com/phanivaranasi/mancycle

This application is built using react + typescript + webpack ..
trying to render map, using ArcGIS with webpack
but getting error **Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'esri/Map'**

Reference https://github.com/Esri/jsapi-resources/tree/master/4.x/webpack/demo as mentioned in youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P0oZWJkYKXg

Kindly help me in fixing the issue.

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWoLv.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing this in your `resolve` portion of your webpack config:

```js
alias: {
    "esri": path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/arcgis-js-api/')
}
```